# How do I implement card swipeup in RecyclerView,GridLayout?

Tags: android

I have a recycler view and cards.I want a gesture like swipe-up to remove the card.My code is:

```
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        data_list = new ArrayList<>();
        load_data();
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,data_list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

CustomAdapterClass:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<MyData> my_data;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<MyData> my_data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.my_data = my_data;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);
    itemView.setMinimumWidth(parent.getMeasuredWidth());
    itemView.setMinimumHeight(parent.getMeasuredHeightAndState());
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.userstory.setText(my_data.get(position).getUserstory());
    holder.tasks.setText(my_data.get(position).getTask());
    holder.actual.setText(my_data.get(position).getActuals());
    holder.estimate.setText(my_data.get(position).getTodos());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return my_data.size();
}

public  class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView userstory,tasks,actual,estimate;
    public CircularSeekBar seekbar;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        userstory=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserStory);
        tasks=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTask);
        actual=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvActual);
        estimate=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEstimate);
    }
}
}
```

I am getting the cards in horizontal scroll view.I want to add swipe gesture to dismiss it
how do I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe this article https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ItemTouchHelper` for recyclerview

Add these lines in onCreate() method of activty.

```
 ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
 itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

And then define Callback for `ItemTouchHelper`..

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "on Move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {

              Toast.makeText(context, "on Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

If you want to get back your swiped data/card then just use this line..

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
```

you can visit :- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html

Comment: Yeah..its working..just changed to ItemTouchHelper.UP..But after a few seconds it is again showing up

Comment: I want to completely remove from the list...If I swipe up 1st item the second one should become the 1st one

Comment: code these lines `arraylist.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`